# Получение максимального значения из столбца - phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Есть столб в базе данных с переменной id, мне надо выбрать ту строчку, где id будет максимальный, в коде php.

Comment: отсортировать столбец id дважды щелкнув по заголовку столбца

Comment: Или отсортировать по уменьшению `id` в запросе. Тогда можно ещё и `LIMIT 1` добавить.

Comment: $conn1 = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "my_password", $dbName);
$tableName = "table";
/* проверка соединения */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", $conn1->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "select * from ".$tableName." where id" ;
$result = $conn1->query($query);
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$record[]=$row2;
}
print_r(max($record));

Comment: @Bloom зачем вытягивать все строки из базы если требуется только 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В интернете очень много информации по этому вопросу:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=(SELECT max(id) FROM table)
```